# How to include oauth library in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, oauth

I found some OAuth library for Java: http://code.google.com/p/oauth/. But how am I supposed to include this library in Eclipse for usage? I've got last classic version of Eclipse. I'm a newbie.

Just want to be able to import i.e. all of those:

```
import net.oauth.client.httpclient4.HttpClient4;
import net.oauth.client.OAuthClient;
import net.oauth.OAuthServiceProvider;
import net.oauth.OAuthConsumer;
import net.oauth.OAuthAccessor;
import net.oauth.OAuth;
import net.oauth.OAuthMessage;
import net.oauth.OAuthException;
```

as in example http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/java/example/command-line/src/net/oauth/example/cmdline/OAuthHelper.java

Comment: right, but how can I build this library from it's source?

Answer (score 0):

1. In Eclipse right click on the project you would like to include the library in and click **properties**.
2. Click on **Java Build Path** and then on the **Libraries** tab.
3. Click **Add External Jar...** and navigate to the library you downloaded.
4. You can now use this in your project!

Comment: Try adding the whole thing to a zip archive. Then change the extension to .jar and follow the steps above. I'm not 100% sure if this will work.

Answer (score 0):

- In a separate project keep all the source files.
- Export **jar** of the project.

  [Creating a New JAR File](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-33.htm)
- Right click on the project you would like to include the **jar** created and click properties.
- Click on **Java Build Path** and then on the **Libraries** tab.
- Click **Add External Jar** and select the jar created.