# How do I get OAuth's java client library with maven?

Tags: maven, oauth

I'm trying to follow this guide here http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-oauthsupport/index.html which gives information on how to use the OAuth client library provided by OAuth and HTTPClient 4 to authenticate your connection. I am working on a Java Swing CLIENT, NOT a OAuth PROVIDER.

OAuth provides a client library here  on this page http://oauth.net/code/

I'm talking about the one marked by "A Java library and examples were contributed by John Kristian, Praveen Alavilli and Dirk Balfanz." which points to an SVN repository http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/java/core/

I do not understand how to incorporate this library into my Eclipse project. I would like to just be able to add a maven dependency because it's so clean and works so well. I don't see coordinates readily available, and when I look at http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/java/pom.xml I see the following coordinates but they don't work when I run the Maven build with the coordinates, and I get a "Missing artifact net.oauth:oauth-parent:jar:20100601" error in Eclipse's integrated Maven 3 pom.xml manager. I thought the entire point of Mavenizing a project was so that you could use its coordinates to pull it in.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>oauth-parent</artifactId>
    <version>20100601</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
</dependency>
```

I've tried the follow dependency after snooping around on the maven repository, and it didn't have all the classes/interfaces/etc I needed.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.oauth.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>oauth</artifactId>
    <version>20100527</version>
</dependency>
```

Is this the wrong way to incorporate this project? Is it not truly mavenized in a way that makes it easy to share? If I can't use Maven, what's the best path to follow to include this library into my project?

This is a bit of a repeat of [How to include oauth library in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262028/how-to-include-oauth-library-in-eclipse) but that question doesn't address the Maven aspect of it at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The OAUth libs doesn't seem to be available in Maven Central, so you have to add the following repository either to your settings.xml or to your pom.xml:

```
<repository>
  <id>oauth</id>
  <name>OAuth Repository</name>
  <url>http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/maven</url>
</repository>
```

Comment: What dependency entry would you add along with this repository entry?

Comment: <groupId>net.oauth.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>oauth</artifactId>
    <version>20100527</version> seems to be the latest, so i would take this

Comment: As of today this repository URL is giving a 404-PageNotFound response.  Would anyone know of an alternative?  Thank you.

Comment: That's five years old - ancient in this age.

Answer (score 2):

I actually found the way to make it work with exactly your version of oauth-parent:

Create a directory and enter it:

```
mkdir oauth && cd oauth
```

Checkout code for your version:

```
svn co http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/java/
```

Enter checked out directory (java), compile and deploy jars yourself:

```
cd java && mvn source:jar install
```

After that your dependency will work:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>oauth-parent</artifactId>
    <version>20100601</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Just attempted in vein to check out from that URL, and I get the following response "E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/java'" followed immediately by "svn: E160013: '/svn/code/java' path not found" WHO MOVED MY CHEESE?

Comment: Hard to tell now after so many years, but source code is probably here now: https://github.com/google/google-oauth-java-client